# SemaphoreSlim cancellation behaves differently in Net6 than Net5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, .net-6.0

I just stumbled upon this weird behavior with Net 6. To me, looks like a bug or so.

Consider this piece of code, where a Task is started, then cancelled by pressing Enter. The Task loops by using a SemaphoreSlim as delay.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("App start");
        using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        var t = new Task(
            async () => await Worker(cts.Token),
            cts.Token,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously
            );

        t.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
        cts.Cancel();

        try
        {
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App ex: " + ex);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("App end");
    }

    static async Task Worker(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task start");
        using SemaphoreSlim semaf = new(0, 1);

        try
        {
            while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Working");
                await semaf.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task ex: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task end");
        }
    }

}
```

If I choose to compile and run this program using **Net 5**, I see something like this in the output console (by pressing Enter right after the "Working" indication):

```
App start
Task start
Working

Task ex: System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Worker(CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\verna\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 51
Task end
App end

C:\Users\verna\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug\net5.0\ConsoleApp3.exe (process 14380) exited with code 0.
```

I'd say, as expected.

However, if I switch to **Net 6**, the output is not what I actually expect:

```
App start
Task start
Working

App end

C:\Users\verna\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp3.exe (process 17144) exited with code 0.
```

That is, the `Worker` function seems leaving way earlier than should do. Even no `finally` executed, which should be guaranteed even in case of fire!

Comment: There are no differences but the code you posted is definitely *not* how tasks are meant to be used. A task isn't a thread. There's never a good reason to call `Task.Start`. Calling `.Wait` on a task defeats the purpose of using tasks in the first place. If you want an asynchronous producer/consumer queue, use System.Threading.Channel. If you only want a throttled worker, use an ActionBlock

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` implementation did change for .NET 6.0; see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/55262

Comment: What is this semaphore meant to be doing anyway? It doesn't seem to serve any purpose  here: the `Worker` method uses a single loop, not multiple tasks or threads that would need synchronization. No other code sets that semaphore, so it acts as an `await Task.Delay(10000);` in the end

Comment: In particular note this comment in the changes: "Awaiter used to await a task.ConfigureAwait(false) but *without throwing any exceptions for faulted or canceled tasks*." (my italics). I suspect that explains the difference.

Comment: @MatthewWatson the implementation, not the semantics. This code is trying to use SemaphoreSlim for something it wasn't built for.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm explaining why the results have changed, not why you shouldn't do it that way. That was the question, after all.

Comment: seems to work fine if you use the more idiomatic `var t = Task.Run(() => Worker(cts.Token), cts.Token);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I accept any different view, also critics, but the cancellation pattern is basically what MS describes. However, despite the unusual usage of the SemaphoreSlim, why that behavior? no finally at all? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Comment: @MarioVernari `"no finally at all?"` - try putting `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of `Main()`. It's exiting before it gets a chance to print "Task end".

Comment: Also after adding the `Console.ReadLine()` you'll likely see the exception message too.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you're right, but...shouldn't the `Wait` block until ALL inside the Worker has be completed, thus the `finally`? do I miss anything?

Comment: `Wait` blocks on its task. It doesn't know anything about nested tasks. In this case, it's a `Task<Task<...>>` because the task is calling an asynchronous delegate.

Comment: @MarioVernari what are you trying to do? .NET already has ready-made classes for implementing pipelines, throttling and async producer/consumer scenarios. If you use low-level constructs complexity will increase a *lot* as you try to combine multiple blocks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my error was about using async/await on the starting delegate. That, as you correctly pointed out, creates an extra indirection which takes out of scope the inner task. Next, was just a different approach, but it got things worse. I believe the different behavior from Net 5 and Net 6 is due to the processing speed, which cuts parts of the execution off the main thread.

Comment: @MarioVernari I think you're right that's the reason for the change. `SemaporeSlim`'s performance has been improved to the extent that you are seeing these different results. See [the performance changes here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/) (search for "SemaphoreSlim")

Comment: You were depending on accidental behavior. That's just one of the reasons it's better to use the correct classes and APIs instead of rolling your own. The other is complexity - you could probably replace all of this code with a single line. Eg, `var block=new ActionBlock<string>(msg=>ProcessMessageAsync(msg));` would be enough to create a worker that asynchronously processes string messages posted to it, buffer incoming messages, guarantee processing order, support cancellation and allow you do specify the degree-of-parallelism. Adding a buffer capacity results in throttling

Comment: With Dataflow blocks you can combine multiple blocks in a single pipeline *and* flow completion, cancellation or errors across the pipeline. This is a lot harder to do if you have to write the code from scratch

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my goal is to start a long-running worker, which should run as the main app lasts. However, when the app closes, that task should end gracefully. In the past I've used Threads for that, but I prefer to avoid to mix threads and tasks. That being said, could you elaborate on Dataflow? you mean Google Dataflow? any link on that? thanks

Comment: They mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

Comment: ah, okay...never used it, clearly! thanks again

Comment: The [Background Tasks with Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) article shows how to create a worker that processes actions posted to a queue, using `Channel` as the async queue. When the application terminates it signals hosted services to gracefully stop through a cancellation token. This example can be modified as needed. Personally I prefer to post messages instead of Funcs to workers and use a separate worker for each "job".

Comment: To summarize the comments, this code has always had a race condition. Previously, one result of that race condition was seen, at least with *some* consistency. .NET 6 included performance improvements which changed the results of the race condition, at least with *some* consistency. The proper solution is to remove the race condition completely.

Comment: @StephenCleary definitely makes sense, thanks.